# How do i charge with card id or customer id using stripe php?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I store card information in database e.g  card-id  `card_*****` and customer id `cus_****` on customer first payment for use it later on. user choose his card e.g in form of radio button `visa****4242` and charge takes with card id or customer id. now i am using stripe modal box for payment. every payment new customer and card id create . how do i charge with card id or customer id on second payment ? here is my stripe code

```
$customer =Stripe_Customer::create(array(
'email' => $_SESSION['userEmail'],));
$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(       
"amount" => $amount_cents,"currency" => "usd","source" => 
$_POST['stripeToken'],"description" => $description,      
));
```

Possible this question may duplicate.But i can not find best answer .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you create a customer you can charge their default card with:

```
\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => $amount_cents,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "customer" => $customer
));
```

If the customer has more than one card and you want to charge a card that isn't the default card, you have to pass in the customer and card id (when the card has already been saved to the customer):

```
\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => $amount_cents,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "customer" => $customer,
  "source" => $card_id
));
```

You can read more about this in Stripe's API docs:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_charge-source

Comment: ok great, but how can i create stripe token with js. now i am using stripe modalbox please

Answer (score 1):

Line 1, you are creating a new customer every time.

You should store the identifier of the customer and source and bind it onto your local customer account.
Next time you can pass those two into Charge.

Comment: but my question is that how do i charge with card id or customer id

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge 
Stripe API documentation is well-written.